# Get dimensions of 2d slice

Tags: go

Lets say I have a `4 by 5` 2d array

```
array := [][]byte{
    {1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
}
```

How do I get the columns and widths of this array? I want to do a nested loop over this array but the array passed in the function may vary in dimensions.

Comment: I don't know go at all, but can't you use `len(array)` and `len(array[0])`?

Comment: Bear in mind that there is no guarantee that each "row" will be the same width - this is just a slice of slices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just get the `len` of `array` and the `len` of any element of `array`.

```
len(array) // 4
len(array[0]) // 5
```

As a note, you are using a 2d slice, not array. Read more about Go slices [here](https://blog.golang.org/slices).